# removeattr not working with parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

removeAttr is not working as everything is correct

```
<input name="phoneno" type="text" class="configradio" id="phoneinput" size="40" data-required="true" data-fixlength10="[10]" data-type="digits"/>

$('#auth_type').on('change',function(){
var typename=document.getElementById('auth_type').value;
$('#resultform').parsley('destroy');
if(typename=="some value"){

$('#phoneinput').removeAttr('data-required');
}
else{
    $('#phoneinput').Attr('data-required',true);
}
$('#resultform').parsley();
});
```

please provide some feedback.

Comment: please provide some error

Comment: no errors but attribute is not removed from input tag

Comment: Instead of 
   $('#phoneinput').removeAttr('data-required');

Try 
   $('#phoneinput').prop('data-required', null );

And please do provide some helpful/more error details which can help us debug what your problem could be

Comment: well, does `typename` ever equal `'some value'`?

Comment: Yes epoch thats working.

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/EQ23T/, I think the problem is Attr with the A in uppercase..

Comment: `#auth_type` would tell us what is this a `select, radio` or `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `removeAttr()` use `removeData()`:

```
$('#phoneinput').removeData('required');
```

Also here is a syntax error `Attr` **a** is a uppercase which should be lowercase `attr`, instead use `prop`, because this is setting the boolean value:

```
$('#phoneinput').prop('data-required',true);
```

or better to use `data()`:

```
$('#phoneinput').data('required', true);
```

Try with this code:

```
$('#auth_type').on('change', function () {
    var typename = this.value;
    $('#resultform').parsley('destroy');
    if (typename == "some value") {
        $('#phoneinput').removeData('required');
    } else {
        $('#phoneinput').data('required', true);
    }
    $('#resultform').parsley();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jai, for the first time it is working. and the problem remains same if i change the selection.

Comment: `#auth_type` would tell us what is this a `select, radio` or `checkbox`?

Comment: #auth_type is a select option.